# Excel: how to do a smart conversion of a string to number?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an automatically created Excel file with a column containing wrongly-formatted numbers. The numbers look like this: `'0.2345` (with a leading apostrophe and with decimal point instead of comma). These numbers cannot be used in any calculations.

I was able to find some articles but they are all not for my case. One of the examples is a [Microsoft Support page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/291047).

I think I need a function something like [PHP's floatval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php) in Excel. Is there any?

Comment: @fixer1234 If I will find an answer by my self I will post an answer!

Comment: It would be best if you asked your questions separately because they don't appear to be related. This will lessen distraction or confusion of one question over the other.

Comment: You're right, @CharlieRB! I removed the needless part of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this work for you?

```
=REPLACE(A2,FIND(".",A2,1),1,",")
```

It will replace the period with a comma in cell A2

Comment: It worked! However I replaced all commas to semicolons (parameters separators). It is strange that it wasn't necessary to remove leading apostrophe.